# JUnit and Netty cause application to end prematurely

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, netty

**Note: I am using JUnit 4.11 and Netty 3.6.5.**

I am trying to test some basic functionality in my complicated server app. I want to extract simply the networking functionality and do some unit tests. However, when I try to create a unit test, the application simply exits. However, if I put a dummy `public static void main`, it works correctly, but outside of JUnit, obviously. Here's the [sscce](http://sscce.org):

```java
public class SimpleNetwork {
    private Injector inj;

    @Before
    public void startInjector() {
        Module mod = new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                // Guice stuff you don't need to see, it works fine
            }
        };
        inj = Guice.createInjector(mod);
    }

    // **When I run this using JUnit, the application ends immediately.**
    @Test
    public void testNetwork() {
        NioServer server = inj.getInstance(NioServer.class);
        server.run();

         // **This prints in both scenarios**
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

    // **When I run this, the application works as expected.**
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleNetwork sn = new SimpleNetwork();

        sn.startInjector();
        sn.testNetwork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you debug into NioServer?

Comment: @fge Yes, the `run` method has a debug `println` that happens

Comment: Netty stuff is *asynchronous*, the test runner doesn't wait for other threads to finish, you have to arrange for that in your test method.

Comment: Junit will exit the test as soon as the junit thread is done whereas your `main` will wait for non daemon threads to terminate before exiting. You need to pause the junit thread and wait for whatever event to happen. It can be a CountdownLatch for example.

Comment: What is `NioServer` code ? Please provide a reference or a snippet.

Comment: @YvesMartin It's very similar to this: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/discard/DiscardServer.java

Comment: @assylias Can you give an example as an answer?

Comment: @durron597 Can you modify the code of your NioServer implementation?

Comment: @assylias Of course I can, but that would defeat the purpose of unit testing

Comment: @durron597 I was a bit too quick in my initial comment. That can't work because the `run` returns immediately and the real server runs in a background thread. See my answer for a proposed alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Junit will exit the test as soon as the junit thread is done whereas your main will wait for non daemon threads to terminate before exiting. You need to pause the junit thread and wait for whatever event to happen.

It is not clear what you are trying to test.

- If you just need to test that your server can start, then your current test does just that. In particular, the link you provide shows a server that runs in a background thread so the `run` method returns immediately. So your test checks that the `run` method returns without problems.
- If you want to actually exercise your server by sending data and checking what is received (for example). In that case, you need to include the code that tests the server in the same test method.

A more typical way of testing something like that would be to start the server once for the whole test class:

```
private NioServer server;
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    server = getServer();
    server.run();
}

@Test
public void testOne() {
    sendSomeDataToServer("data");
    assertEquals("data", server.getLastReceivedData());
}
```

(I am not 100% sure about the JUnit syntax as I use testNG but it should be something like that)

Comment: This class is part of the server testing environment. Are you saying, start the server in `@BeforeClass`, then make some client connections to itself?

Comment: @durron597 That is one way yes. Another way would be to use mock objects. What exactly are you trying to test? When do you expect the test to pass or fail? If you clarify that it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Huh. Asking that question makes me wonder if my approach is trying to cover too much code all at once. I started to type "make sure the server constructs and deconstructs objects correctly" except why aren't I testing the encoders directly then?

Comment: @durron597 In which case one approach would be to mock the server and manually pass a message and check that the output of the decoding method is as expected (for example).

Comment: Anyway, this was helpful; I might give this the bounty but I'm going to wait the 5 days.

Comment: @durron597 Sure you should wait and see if you get more answers. 2 last things: (a) Learning to use a mocking framework can take a bit of time but it is a good investment, and would help you solve that sort of issue elegantly. (b) in the code you linked earlier, there is not much to test in DiscardServer. The core of the server (decoding/encoding) really is in the DiscardServerHandler which you should test separately.